# Fedora phpMyAdmin "Cannot log in to the MySQL server", yet MySql cmd line is ok

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, fedora, selinux

Fedora release 23 (Twenty Three) - I installed phpMyAdmin, I navigate to it (http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/index.php, or using http://localhost...). `id=root`, and my password does not work, just get the message `Cannot log in to the MySQL server`.

Yet, I can log into MySql using, `sudo mysql -u root -p` and entering my password. From `mysql` I even tried changing my password (to the same thing) using:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD("mypasswordhere") WHERE User="root"; and, FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

but still cannot log into phpmyadmin.

Again, can log into MySql via command line, but cannot log into phpMyAdmin. trying port `8889` does not work, either. Only `80` default gets me to the login page. Help?

Comment: See This [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/583797/cant-login-to-remote-mariadb-server-with-phpmyadmin-but-works-in-shell). I hope meet your answer.

Comment: When you use command line, you are not giving a host name (with -h) so I wonder what is the output of "SELECT CURRENT_USER();".

Comment: hi, Marc, that select stmt returns this: current_user() = root@localhost. so, i tried root@localhost as userid, but same error in phpmyadmin: Cannot log in to the MySQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Important part from the question on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/583797/cant-login-to-remote-mariadb-server-with-phpmyadmin-but-works-in-shell):

Make sure you have allowed SELinux boolean:

```
# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on
```

It should probably help investigating SELinux messages in audit (`ausearch -m AVC`) or **temporarily** switch SELinux to Permissive mode (`setenforce 0`) to make sure it is the real cause.

Comment: oh my, i ran setenforce 0 and now i can get into phpmyadmin. this is great news! *however* is it ok to run my system with selinux set to Permissive, permanently? doing a sudo vi /etc/selinux/config, setting to Permissive. this will be my first effort, though, until something possibly better comes along. meanwhile, thank you, Jakuje! can someone tell me how to give ppl points? i can vote up +1, but i do not know how to praise answers officially.

Comment: No. it is not ok to run with selinux inpermissive mode. If the above mentioned boolean does not work for you, there will be some similar as described in [wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans)